# Using regex in PHP to replace tags with its content to new tags with some old and some new content

Tags: php, regex

I have this text:

```
$string = '
And God<WH430> said<WH559>, Behold<WH2009>, I have given<WH5414> you every herb<WH6212>
bearing<WH2232> seed<WH2233>, which <FI>is<Fi> upon the face<WH6440> of all the 
earth<WH776>, and every tree<WH6086>, in the which <FI>is<Fi> the fruit<WH6529> of a 
tree<WH6086> yielding<WH2232> seed<WH2233>; to you it shall be<WH1961> for meat<WH402>.
<RF>bearing...: Heb. seeding seed<Rf><RF>yielding...: Heb. seeding seed<Rf>';
```

And this code:

```
$search = '/<RF>(.*)<Rf>/';
$replace = '&nbsp;<sup data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="$1"> note </sup>';
$string = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

I want the regex to replace every  tag individually, but with this code I get this:

```
And God<WH430> said<WH559>, Behold<WH2009>, I have given<WH5414> you every herb<WH6212>
bearing<WH2232> seed<WH2233>, which <FI>is<Fi> upon the face<WH6440> of all the 
earth<WH776>, and every tree<WH6086>, in the which <FI>is<Fi> the fruit<WH6529> of a 
tree<WH6086> yielding<WH2232> seed<WH2233>; to you it shall be<WH1961> for meat<WH402>.
<sup data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="bearing...: Heb. seeding seed<Rf>
<RF>yielding...: Heb. seeding seed"> note </sup>
```

So, it just jumps over the tags in in the middle, and gos on until the final one in the end of the text... How can I get every instance of ...some tekst... replaced individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is too greedy, so the `.*` is consuming as much text as possible. Modify it to:

```
/<RF>(.*?)<Rf>/
        ^
        Added question mark
```

This will cause the regex to capture *as little* text as necessary to match the expression.

Comment: Thanks! So far I have not been able to understand what the / in the beginning and the end is for, just that they need to be there... could you enlighten me? :)

Comment: @JErik - They're called the [regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the your text doesn't contain `<`, you can do this:

```
$search = '~<RF>([^<]*+)<Rf>~';
```

otherwise you can use:

```
$search = '~<RF>((?>[^<]++|<(?!Rf>))*+)<Rf>~';
```